# How to document kwargs in Sphinx style?

Tags: python, documentation

I'm wondering how I can document `**kwargs` in Python using sphinx dostring style.

For example I have the following method and I want to document more details about kwargs.

```
  def get(self, url=None, **kwargs):
    """
    InsReq get (overriding)
    :param url: url
    :type url: str
    :param kwargs: How to document these most used parameters?
    :type kwargs: dict
    :return: response object
    :rtype: requests.models.Response
    """
    [...]
```

method usage:

`>>> obj.get(url='http://google.com', delay=10, retries=5)`

Have you any idea which is the "proper" way to document these extra parameters?

Comment: SO dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1137161/3001761

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use inline literals like:

```
`**kwargs`
```

or inline blocks like

```
::
    **kwargs
```

For more information look [here](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#inline-markup-recognition-rules)